# How do I make this concave shape?

Tags: mesh, materials, modifiers, uv, edit-mode

So i have a disk to make for my dad. He wants to buy a 3d printer and i need to make this shape. I have looked every where over the internet and couldn't find a tutorial to make a shape like this one. Can anyone help me?[image]

Comment: this is like a cylinder, you need to scale its edges so that it gets thiner towards the bottom, what difficulty have you met?

Comment: yeah, show us what you tried so far. This is not a "we do all the work for you"-platform, but a "we help you with what you made so far"-platform.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111986/simple-way-to-create-a-curved-tunnel-between-two-planes/112004#112004

Comment: Sorry I haven't been on the pc for a few days. I was thinking i could make a cylinder to make the base and the make an uv sphere, then i used the boolean modifier but it didn't look like the picture from above

Answer (score 2):

**Welcome on the forums, to get you started...**
I used a modifier to spiral a curve line
next added a modifier to make it solid
next added 4 cylinders by mirroring one.
next i did a boolean operation to subtract the 4 cylinders.

for visibility i altered the 4 cylinders so you see them as wire frame.

[image]

Note you can change this file, the modifiers, or in edit mode change the curve or the cylinders.

Comment: nice work!!!!!!

Comment: nice work but i tried doing the same thing you did and its looking not even close to what you did.

Comment: its probaply because of the settings I used to have more in betweens than the default for the spiral.modifier