# I want to treat shapekey's keyblocks collection like a List

Tags: python, scripting

[In a past question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234765/is-there-a-faster-way-to-control-the-shapekey-in-python/234778?noredirect=1#comment398046_234778), I learned that using `foreach_set` for a collection in shapekey can speed up the process.

However, I don't know how to create a collection with shapekey.

I have tried the following code.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

ob = context.object
me = ob.data
sks = me.shape_keys

key_blockList = []
shapeKeyValueList = [0.0,0.1,0.2]

if sks:
    for block in sks.key_blocks:
        key_blockList.append(block)

key_blockList = sorted(key_blockList, key=lambda key_block: (key_block.name))

key_blockList.foreach_set("value", shapeKeyValueList)
```

Then I got the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'foreach_set'
```

The error message says that list objects and collections are different things.

I also tried to see if I could add shapekey to the collection.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

ob = context.object
me = ob.data
sks = me.shape_keys

key_blockList = bpy.data.collections.new("test")
shapeKeyValueList = [0.0,0.1,0.2]

if sks:
    for block in sks.key_blocks:
        key_blockList.link(block)

key_blockList = sorted(key_blockList, key=lambda key_block: (key_block.name))

key_blockList.foreach_set("value", shapeKeyValueList)
```

But,I got a following error.

```
AttributeError: 'Collection' object has no attribute 'ShapeKey'
```

I would like to know how to add shapekey to a collection, remove it, or initialize a collection.

Python's List allows us to reorder, remove and add elements. sks.key_blocks is inconvenient for me because it doesn't allow me to reorder, remove and add elements. I don't want to reorder them in a way that is visible to the user, I just want to reorder and remove elements as variables.

When I add key_blocks in the list, foreach_set is no longer available. But if I keep the collection, I can't figure out how to reorder or remove elements. I don't want the user to see the change in the order.

Comment: The `foreach_set` method is not creating the objects, it is setting a property value to all objects in a collection, from a list of values.  Use `ob.shape_key_add(...)` to add a new key block.  Example https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/93180/15543

Comment: Hard to tell, but I think you want something lik  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116633/adding-multiple-shape-keys-with-python-and-bmesh-while-creating-a-mesh to add shapekeys   Actually, reading again Not a Blender Collection (like in outliner) used as a term for a collection of shapekeys _eg_ `sks.key_blocks` where an object in that collection is a shape key.

Comment: The `shape_key_add` command adds keyblocks to a shapekey that does not have any keyblocks.
However, I don't want to add keyblocks to the shapekey.
What I want to do is to extract keyblocks from a shapekey that already has keyblocks. Then I want to treat the extracted keyblocks like a list.

Comment: `sks.key_blocks[:]` is a list.  A blender object collection _ie_ a `bpy_prop_collection` like `bpy.data.objects` or `sks.key_blocks` has a `foreach_set` method, a python `list` does not.  Hard to get a read on what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I already have a list of shapekey values like `[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5 ....]`. I want to assign this values to `[keyblock_a, keyblock_b, keyblock_c, keyblock_d, keyblock_e ....]` with `foreach_set`. However, depending on the user's environment, the order of keyblocks may be different, such as `[keyblock_c, keyblock_b, keyblock_a, keyblock_e, keyblock_d ....]`. Therefore, it is difficult to use `foreach_set`.

Comment: Consider then making queston that.  Remove , what are IMO  unnecessary references  to `bpy.data.collections`, and `list` not having a `foreach_set`,   The `sks.key_blocks` is in the order seen in UI, in general with "Basis" at zero index (on top).  If your list of values is in name order, then to set with `foreach_set` sort your list to match the order of the key blocks.

Comment: OK,Thank you for the reply!