# How do I close a circle without having to deal with tris and ngons?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, vertices

Here's the circle:

[image: Circle]

I've always been extruding and then scaling the circle inwards. But when I then make a face, there's an ngon. It's not very noticeable, so I've been sticking to that method all the time. But now I am wondering if there's a method that involves only quads. Would that even be possible?

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30738/how-can-i-morph-a-flat-plane-to-be-a-flat-cirlce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there must be several ways to do it, like the following ones, I'm not sure how it could be useful though. As said by Robin, an easy way to begin is to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> > *Grid Fill*, then modify the grid that has been created with some <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> to make your selection round:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One handy thing to know is that, given an empty circle  with an even number of edges, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> > *Grid Fill* will choose the right number of spans, and do the right thing to generate this pattern:

[image]

If you suspect you will want to retain an edge-loop around the outside for convenient beveling. extruding, and so on, it may be better to inset the circle first, just filling the center hole this way.