# Effective modelling of polar array

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

What would be the best way to achieve a quad mesh model of this kind of surface:
[image: reference image]

The object has 12 circular arrays, with 6 holes on the innermost ring, then 12, 18, 24 ... plus 6 per each ring. Please note that the hole diameter is constant.

Modeling each ring with an polar array is possible, but this results in a heavy workload of retopo. I also tried the tissue addon, but could not manage to get clean meshes at a glance.

Answer (score 7):

If you run this baby script:

```
import bpy

idx = 1
vtx = 6
rad = 0.25
inc = 0.25

while (idx < 14):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(vertices=vtx, radius=rad)
    rad += inc
    vtx += 6
    idx += 1
```

It will create a series of concentric circles with the right number of vertices. (I'm sure a proper Pythonista could do it in one line, and automate some of the steps which follow...)

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> Join the circles into one object
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Bridge Edge Loops each pair of loops in turn, and <kbd>F</kbd>..<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, fan-fill the center.
- You wind up with a mesh with one or two diagonals out of place. I'm not sure it would matter, but I cut 1/6 out as shown, corrected the edges, and arrayed it back to a full circle)
- Select all vertices except those on the perimeter, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevel them, and switch to Face mode. The future holes should be selected.
- Loop-Tools or Space-Bar > 'Circle' with a radius setting, on the selected hole-faces.
- Delete the faces
- Extrude or add a Solidify modifier, and throw on a Subdivision modifier.

[image]

The holes aren't *perfectly* circular but maybe good enough?

[image]

Comment: Hmm, it's not quad... but it is after one level of subdiv....

Comment: Reminds me of the stretching and Shirley mappings https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/93180/15543

Comment: @batFINGER Could that have been a way through, I wonder.. I wasn't very Pythonic in those days, was I? Only a little more now, to tell the truth..

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to all of you for your support. After some thinking, i came up with this method:
[image]

[image]

[[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Doing this manually is not the fastest method, but i think in terms of topology this is the best result. Maybe someone can do a script to perform the steps.

Comment: Very nice... :) I can't help thinking there's a neater way than both of these...