# Multiple holes in circular direction

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to get the outer holes going in a circular direction the circular mesh in the middle is clean, and so are the holes when left intact without applying the loop tools> circle.

I tried 2 methods of getting a better result, but both times I'm moving the mesh around and needs cleaning up, using knife tool to make more faces, which result in triangle faces.

What would be the best way to approach this type of modelling getting good topology and clean circular ellipses?

Thank you.

[image]

Reference image:

[image]
*An example done in Adobe Illustrator. Its basically just smaller globes going around the larger globe which is in the middle.*

Comment: Have you tried using a Boolean Modifier?

Comment: I'm avoiding the Boolean modifier at all cost, it would create ngons and unclean topology on the mesh.

Comment: Smart to avoid the boolean. It would result in terrible topology. I'm confused by your description of circular circles and circular ellipses, can you show a sketch or reference image of the final result you are after? Usually for symmetrical patterns you just create a quarter of the mesh, then use mirror modifiers to complete.

Comment: Here is an example done in Adobe Illustrator. Its basically just smaller globes going around the larger globe which is in the middle. https://ibb.co/n7C9MCL

Comment: Please use the edit tool to add information to the post. Make the images visible on this page. Don't make users work extra just to help you.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123572/effective-modelling-of-polar-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution for this kind of object. After step 3 I've assigned a *Mirror* modifier to the object so that you only need to work on 1/4 of the object. Remember that the center of the mirror is at the origin of the object, and activate the *Clipping* option. You can keep the *Mirror* as long as necessary, you can even apply, work on your object, then feel the need to bring back a new *Mirror*. After the extrusion on the Z axis, make sure you've not created some inner face, otherwise it will mess up the mesh. Give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, add some edge loops to sharp the edges.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it. (The circular shape extrusion wont be needed). Can you please explain what you did you getting the smaller holes going around?

Thank you.

Comment: I just began with 1 hexagon (which is the minimum shape to get good circles in my opinion) that I duplicated / rotated around a center, then keep only 1/4 and mirror on X and Y, join together with some fill faces, etc...

Comment: OK, thanks heaps for that!

Kind regards.

Comment: I've edited, I hope it makes it more understandable

Comment: Too good, excellent demo! 

Cheers!

Comment: I use the Mirror modifier on both the X and Y axis. Remember that the center of the mirror is at the origin of the object. Sometimes you can apply the mirror, work on the object, then feel the need to bring back a new mirror to work only on 1/4, so delete the 3/4, etc...