# how to turn a square into a circle in 2.8

Tags: mesh

In blender 2.79 there was an ability "to circle", i believe, that took a series of vertices and made a circle with them. i am not finding that ability anywhere in 2.8, is it gone?

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30738/how-can-i-morph-a-flat-plane-to-be-a-flat-cirlce)

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand your question. What do you mean create a circle from a group of faces? Or from a square (which is different)?
To create a new "Circle" primitive there is an "Add" menu just on top of the viewport. To "round up" a (decently created) geometry that already exists, which doesn't make a *circle* but a more rounded shape, you can use Subdivision Surface as explained by Nobimberg.

Comment: I believe that's a feature from an add-on, loop tools. I am not sure whether it is available in 2.8 but it should be, once the developer managed to update the code for the new 2.80 API

Comment: There was To Circle operator which had Shift+Alt+S shortcut in 2.79 and below. It didn't work quite reliably as LoopTools counterpart but it seems to me that's what OP is asking about

Comment: LoopTools addon has an operator 'Circle' that does this. Since the topic is on hold, I cannot answer but if you enable the Looptools addon, you will find the operator on the W key>Looptools>Circle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I morph a flat plane to be a flat cirlce?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30738/how-can-i-morph-a-flat-plane-to-be-a-flat-cirlce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a plane like the one in the picture below, to transform it into a circle you want to use the **Subdivision Surface Modifier**.

[image]

To do this, select first your model, then select the little wrench icon you find on the left of the properties panel which is on the bottom right of the user interface (the one pointed by the red arrow in the second picture) then click on **Add Modifier**. You're going to see a dropdown list, select the Subdivision Surface Modifier from there.

[image][image]

Once you've selected it you're going to see something like in the second picture on your properties panel, while the plane will look like the picture below.

[image]

What you want to do now is increase the value of the **View** and **Render** properties on the modifier. These basically increase the number of subdivisions on your model: the first one is just for the viewport, the second is for the actual render of your model, if they are different your model will look different in the viewport and when you render it.
By setting both values to 3 I was able to transform the plane into the circle in the picture below, which I think is enough.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for ***To Sphere***.

Go into *Edit Mode*, select the vertices you want to change, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and move the mouse till you get the shape you want (or use the menu *Mesh* > *Transform* > *To Sphere*).

[image]

<kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> to confirm changes, <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> to cancel.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to activate an addon called loop tools.

Comment: Could you expand on this answer, such as explaining how the loop tools addon will help, and how to use the circularize tool there? LoopTools is probably a better solution to the problem in the original question than the existing accepted answer, but your answer is a bit incomplete as is.