# 2D morphing from square to circle

Tags: animation

I am a beginner in 2D animation . Would be grateful if somebody guide me how to animate change of shapes, eg from square to circle. Thanks !

Comment: do you want to do it with the grease pencil?

Comment: This is done with shape keys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I morph a flat plane to be a flat cirlce?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30738/how-can-i-morph-a-flat-plane-to-be-a-flat-cirlce)   or   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129197/how-to-turn-a-square-into-a-circle-in-2-8