# tensor flow / deformable grid

Tags: python, mesh, workflow, force-fields

I am trying to make a grid that i can deform, by adding points that acts like a magnetic field.
Is it possible to create a grid that i can manually/auto deform like this?

[image]

I need it to be one connected mesh and not multiple objects:
[image][image]
I am trying to recreate something like the tensor field on this site :
https://probabletrain.itch.io/city-generator

EDIT:
The closets i could get to what i want is by using a sphere modifier with a circle as control:
[image]

But this creates weird geometry. Anyone another idea?

Comment: you could try adding track to constraints to each grid cell to make them point to some target, and then move that target around.

Comment: That is what i did here, but i need to create a mesh out of it. (see the image i added)

Comment: Hi Alex, Could you say a bit more why you need it to be one mesh? I can imagine having a plane with 10x10 faces, with on each cross section two edges, you place a bone. Then placing a track to or other aim constraint on the bone, so it aims at the central object. This would accurately get the rotation, and transfer that onto the mesh without adding weird scaling to it like your above example.

Comment: Becuase i am making a script that makes a map, and i t works simply by manipulating the geometry and then beveling the edges to makes roads. That is also why i can't have weird geometry

Comment: You said the circle method creates some weird geo. what is a weird geometry for your purposes? If you could give an example for the mesh equivalent of the empties, it would be very helpful to know how to convert empties to meshes.

Comment: Wonder if something could be done via https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/153181/15543  script wise could use something like https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/93180/15543  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/93180/15543   Wonder too if your to sphere result can be tweaked using multiple concentric spheres to cubes of differing influence or modifier order  to keep inner verts more circular outer more square.

Comment: I've got some results but wasn't sure that's what you wanted. so I uplaoded a video of it [here](https://streamable.com/vz2h16). let me know if you are interested.