# How to unwrap for detailed face

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

What I have and what I did:

[image]

I have 1 mesh. Now I need to unwrap it considering high detailed head(face). So, I separated head by selection and did unwrap for each one. I got my goal, then I need to join head with body. I joined it and there it is:

[image]

So, I pressed `Ctrl+A`, then unwrapped again, and got this one:

[image]

It seems to be okay, but, I lost details on the face. Even if I scale it, it turns green/yellow.

What I need:

When I connect head with body and unwrap it, quads on head turns larger.
I need to get the result like on the first screen, connecting two meshes(head and body), if it is possible, or can you recommend me any ways to go or show me my mistakes?

I tried to use tiles, but didn't get results that I need.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Unwrapping head geometry similar to Epic's MetaHuman Characters?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/221373/78972)

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is: how to connect head mesh with body mesh not losing high detalization on head. I will edit my post.

Comment: If you want to have more details on the head then you need to scale up the UV island of the head and shrink down the island of the body. If you want to keep the sizes as shown in screenshots 1 and 2 then use tiled textures (UDIMs).

Comment: I scaled up the uv island of the head, but the stretch area turned into yellow colour. I guess it is not good. Also I used tiled textures, the stretch area was orange, maybe i didn't use it properly. I'll check it.

Comment: Is the stretching overlay of the *angle* or *area* type? *Angle* is the default. Just tried to resize the face but the color does not change for this type. It does for *area* and the island turns red.

Comment: There is an area, but when i choose angle, it turns into blue. So, do I need to igrore yellow “area” ?

Comment: Yes, the stretch overlay shows how much of a difference there is between UV coordinates and 3D coordinates. *Area* type is good to check that everything has the same level of detail. But you *want* to have a higher detail on the head and scaled it up. So it turns yellow, later red. That's totally fine. The *area* type does basically with color what the checkboard texture does with the squares.

Comment: You saved my time, thanks a lot.