# Where to apply seams when unwrapping a head?

Tags: uv

Just wondered if there's a 'benchmark / gold standard' for where to apply seams when unwrapping a head, i.e; include ears in the main island or exclude them, - where to roughly start and stop the center-seam etc etc.

If there's a good tutorial that you've seen, or you've already got great methodology published on the web somewhere, I'd love to see it... I just can't seem to find a set of joins that I'm totally happy with.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it depends on how you plan to texture your head, if you plan to paint on it you can simply unwrap with the Smart UV Project, it doesn't need any seam

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: One technique is to unwrap the face vertically and symmetrically so you can easily edit the image texture in an image editor. If you want to have the scalp, ears on separate UV islands depends on how much texture space and details you want to give them. To use the space effectively you can unwrap the face with closed eyes and mouth. Game modes are often unwrapped like this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/221373/107598 - Here is a live stream from Blender Studio: https://youtu.be/_LI28r-Nk5g and here a tutorial: https://youtu.be/ZyRtd8iYBOg